# How should I model log or sqrt with GEKKO? Constraints

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, sqrt, gekko

I'm trying to develop my constraints with GEKKO, and I need to include some mathematical operations as log, coth or sqrt.

I tried initially with my habitual procedures, using numpy or mpmath, but I figure out that using GEKKO I need to use their operator definitions, as m.wathever (log,...), once the m = GEKKO() is done

How is the best way to develop that?
Should I take some considerations while I'm changing it?

```
K_t = (1 + m + np.sqrt(1 + m**3)) - mpmath.coth(s/2)  # Ref 2. Same results
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Gekko versions of those functions instead of the NumPy or Math versions:

```py
gk = GEKKO()
K_t = (1 + m + gk.sqrt(1 + m**3)) - gk.cosh(s/2)/gk.sinh(s/2)
```

The Gekko versions are needed because of operator overloading to calculate first and second derivatives for the solvers with automatic differentiation. There is no `coth` so you'll need to substitute with `coth(x) = cosh(x)/sinh(x)`. I typically define my Gekko model as `m=GEKKO()` but you have another variable named `m` so I used `gk` instead. Here is a section from the [documentation on Model Building Functions](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model_methods.html?#equation-functions).

**Equation Functions**

Special function besides algebraic operators are available through GEKKO functions. These must be used (not numpy or other equivalent functions):

- gk.sin(other)
- gk.cos(other)
- gk.tan(other)
- gk.asin(other)
- gk.acos(other)
- gk.atan(other)
- gk.sinh(other)
- gk.cosh(other)
- gk.tanh(other)
- gk.exp(other)
- gk.log(other)
- gk.log10(other)
- gk.sqrt(other)

Answer (score 0):

One related observation about `sqrt` is that solution robustness improves by protecting against the case where the argument is negative. Here is a simple system using `gekko`:

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
m = GEKKO()
m.time = np.linspace(0,20,100)
k = 5
y = m.Var(value=5.0)
t = m.Param(value=m.time)

m.Equation(k*y.dt()==-m.sqrt(y))
m.options.IMODE = 4
m.solve(disp=True)
```

It seems to get stuck at `sqrt` probably because it can become less than zero and `gekko` solvers need additional equations to handle [complex numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74645998/is-it-possible-to-use-gekko-for-curve-fitting-if-complex-numbers-can-appear-in-i). Changing the equation to remove `sqrt` with `m.Equation((-k*y.dt())**2==y)` is a potential solution to this problem:

[image: solution]

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
m = GEKKO()
m.time = np.linspace(0,20,100)
k = 5
y = m.Var(value=5.0)
t = m.Param(value=m.time)

m.Equation((-k*y.dt())**2==y)
m.options.IMODE = 4
m.solve(disp=True)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(m.time,y)
plt.show()
```

Another strategy is to constrain the argument of `sqrt` to be greater than zero such as with `y = m.Var(value=5.0,lb=0)` or `y.LOWER=0`. This also works to find a successful solution with the original equation.

```
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
m = GEKKO()
m.time = np.linspace(0,20,100)
k = 5
y = m.Var(value=5.0,lb=0)
t = m.Param(value=m.time)

m.Equation(k*y.dt()==-m.sqrt(y))
m.options.IMODE = 4
m.solve(disp=True)
```