# Is it possible to use GEKKO for curve fitting if complex numbers can appear in intermediate steps?

Tags: optimization, complex-numbers, gekko

I am trying to use GEKKO for optimization purposes, particularly for curve-fitting, functions have a relatively large number of parameters.

For example:

```
f1 = f(par_1, par_2, par_3, ... , par_n)
```

Functions can be defined explicitly (not black-box functions) and all parameters have real values.

`par_1, par_2, ..., par_n` have real values.

All outputs of the f1 and the data for fitting are always real,
but some intermediate calculation steps can result in complex values (real and non-zero imaginary parts).

I am using Steady-State (MPU) mode for the estimation of parameters.

Is it possible to use GEKKO in this case?
Or maybe it depends on the solver selected?

Answer (score 1):

Gekko does not natively handle complex numbers. The automatic differentiation and gradient-based solvers haven't been programmed with that in mind. There are workarounds to solve complex number problems by splitting the variable. Below is an example that maximizes the imaginary number `yr + yi i` as the square root of `x`. The variable `x` is a decision that the optimizer can adjust to maximize the objective.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO()
x = m.Var(2,lb=-9,ub=16)     # -9<=x<=16
b = m.if3(x,0,1)             # binary switch
s = m.Intermediate(m.sqrt(m.abs3(x))) # sqrt(x)
yr = m.Intermediate(b*s)     # real
yi = m.Intermediate((1-b)*s) # imaginary

m.Maximize(yi**2)            # maximize imaginary number
m.solve()
print(yr.value[0],'+',yi.value[0],'i')
```

This produces the correct solution:

```py
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  APOPT (v1.0)
 Solution time  :   3.800000000046566E-002 sec
 Objective      :   -9.00000000000000     
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
 
0.0 + 3.0 i
```

There are additional suggestions at [Application of complex numbers in Linear Programming?](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/560/application-of-complex-numbers-in-linear-programming)