# GEKKO fails to solve simple model - why?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, gekko

I have formulated a very simple model, but GEKKO fails to solve it (with standard settings and `MAX_ITER = 100000`). I'm trying to understand why GEKKO struggles in this case. This is the model:

```
from gekko import GEKKO

m = GEKKO()
x = m.Var(value=15.0, lb=10.0, ub=20.0, name="x")
y = m.Intermediate(-5.0, name="y")
z = m.Intermediate(y, name="z")
r = m.Intermediate(200000.0 * z ** 0.5, name="r")
obj_expr = r - x
m.Maximize(obj_expr)
m.options.MAX_ITER = 10000
m.solve()
```

```
EXIT: Invalid number in NLP function or derivative detected.
An error occured.
The error code is          -13 
Exception:  @error: Solution Not Found
```

The optimal solution is obvious: Since `y = -5`, `z = -5`. Hence, `r = 200000.0 * -5 ** 0.5 = -447213.59549995797`. The objective is to maximize `r - x`. `r` cannot be changed. Therefore, `x` should be set to the lower bound.

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `z` is `-5` so `-5**0.5` is `2.236i`, but the solvers don't implicitly handle complex numbers. One way to protect against negative values is to make `z` a variable and set a lower bound such as:

```py
z = m.Var(lb=1e-5)
m.Equation(z==y)
```

However, this would lead to an infeasible solution if `y=-5`. Another way is to create the intermediate variable so that negative numbers aren't a problem:

```py
r = m.Intermediate(200000.0 * (z**2) ** 0.25, name="r")
```

This protects against negative numbers. Here is a complete script that solves successfully:

```py
from gekko import GEKKO

m = GEKKO()
x = m.Var(value=15.0, lb=10.0, ub=20.0, name="x")
y = m.Intermediate(-5.0, name="y")
z = m.Intermediate(y, name="z")
r = m.Intermediate(200000.0 * (z**2) ** 0.25, name="r")
obj_expr = r - x
m.Maximize(obj_expr)
m.options.MAX_ITER = 10000
m.solve()
```

Here is a way to handle complex numbers, if needed: [Is it possible to use GEKKO for curve fitting if complex numbers can appear in intermediate steps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74645998/is-it-possible-to-use-gekko-for-curve-fitting-if-complex-numbers-can-appear-in-i)