# The error message"Solution Not Found" pops up when I try to find the squre root value

Tags: python, root, gekko, square

I made a code and it worked well before I added a line to find square root value.

The code is composed of simple calculations. I am trying to get the values because I will need to find derivatives of them.

I saw the values I tried to get the square root value and they are not negative values.

Please give me some hints for this.

here's the code

```
from gekko import GEKKO
from tqdm import tqdm
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
m = GEKKO(remote=False)

m.time=np.linspace(0.000,0.046875,300)
#Variables
t = m.Param(m.time) #Time
h2 = 4.907/180*math.pi #arm 각도범위
beta2 = 40/360*2*math.pi #cam 할부각

rr1 = 292 #length of link1
rr2 = 398 #length of link2
rr3 = 130 #length of link3
rr0 = 429.71 #length of link0
rr11 = 260
rr22 = 639.5
rr33 = 260
theta20 = 112.4853/360*2*math.pi
theta25 = 2*math.pi/3*t 
theta200 = math.pi/2
theta233 = 0
theta21 = m.Var() #input 1

A2 = m.Var()
B2 = m.Var()
C2 = m.Var()
K2 = m.Var()
theta23 = m.Var() #output 1
theta211 = theta23 + math.pi

AA2 = m.Var()
BB2 = m.Var()
KK2 = m.Var()
rr00 = m.Var() #output 2
rr000 = m.Var() #Velocity of output
rr0000 = m.Var() #acceleration of output

m.Equation(theta21 == -math.pi+h2/2-h2*(0.43989*theta25/beta2-0.035014*m.sin(4*math.pi*theta25/beta2)))

m.Equation(A2 == 2*rr0*rr3*m.cos(theta20)-2*rr1*rr3*m.cos(theta21))
m.Equation(B2 == 2*rr0*rr3*m.sin(theta20)-2*rr1*rr3*m.sin(theta21))
m.Equation(C2 == rr0**2+rr1**2+rr3**2-rr2**2-2*rr0*rr1*(m.cos(theta20)*m.cos(theta21)+m.sin(theta20)*m.sin(theta21)))

m.Equation(K2 == (-B2-(B2**2-C2**2+A2**2)**(1/2))/(C2-A2))
m.Equation(theta23 == m.atan(K2)*2)

m.Equation(AA2 == 2*rr33*(m.cos(theta200)*m.cos(theta233)+m.sin(theta200)*m.sin(theta233))-2*rr11*(m.cos(theta200)*m.cos(theta211)+m.sin(theta200)*m.sin(theta211)))
m.Equation(BB2 == rr11**2+rr33**2-rr22**2-2*rr11*rr33*(m.cos(theta211)*m.cos(theta233)+m.sin(theta211)*m.sin(theta233)))

m.Equation(rr00 == (-AA2+(AA2**2-4*BB2)**(1/2))/2)

m.options.IMODE=6
m.solve(disp=False)
df = pd.DataFrame([m.time, rr00.value])
df.to_csv('D:/pyyhon/2축 힘 변화/test.csv',\
index=None)
plt.plot(m.time, rr00.value)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

The square root produces a complex number when the operand is negative. There is a way to handle complex numbers in Gekko such as shown in: [Is it possible to use GEKKO for curve fitting if complex numbers can appear in intermediate steps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74645998/is-it-possible-to-use-gekko-for-curve-fitting-if-complex-numbers-can-appear-in-i/) However, it is also possible to rearrange the equation to avoid the possibility of a complex number and improve convergence. Here is one way to rearrange the equation into an equivalent form that solves reliably.

```py
#m.Equation(rr00 == (-AA2+(AA2**2-4*BB2)**(1/2))/2)
m.Equation((2*rr00+AA2)**2 == AA2**2-4*BB2)
```

A few other suggestions on the model:

- Use `m.Intermediate()` variables where possible to reduce the number of implicitly solved variables and increase the solution performance.

```py
# Input 1
theta21 = m.Intermediate(-math.pi+h2/2-h2*(0.43989*theta25/beta2-0.035014*m.sin(4*math.pi*theta25/beta2)))
A2 = m.Intermediate(2*rr0*rr3*m.cos(theta20)-2*rr1*rr3*m.cos(theta21))
B2 = m.Intermediate(2*rr0*rr3*m.sin(theta20)-2*rr1*rr3*m.sin(theta21))
C2 = m.Intermediate(rr0**2+rr1**2+rr3**2-rr2**2-2*rr0*rr1*(m.cos(theta20)*m.cos(theta21)+m.sin(theta20)*m.sin(theta21)))
K2 = m.Intermediate((-B2-(B2**2-C2**2+A2**2)**(1/2))/(C2-A2))
theta23 = m.Intermediate(m.atan(K2)*2)
theta211 = m.Intermediate(theta23 + math.pi)

AA2 = m.Intermediate(2*rr33*(m.cos(theta200)*m.cos(theta233)+m.sin(theta200)*m.sin(theta233))-2*rr11*(m.cos(theta200)*m.cos(theta211)+m.sin(theta200)*m.sin(theta211)))
BB2 = m.Intermediate(rr11**2+rr33**2-rr22**2-2*rr11*rr33*(m.cos(theta211)*m.cos(theta233)+m.sin(theta211)*m.sin(theta233)))
```

- Remove variables that have no associated equation or include an equation.

```py
# Remove A22

# Add equations for velocity and acceleration
m.Equation(rr00.dt()==rr000)
m.Equation(rr000.dt()==rr0000)
```

Here is a complete script that solves successfully in simulation.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
from tqdm import tqdm
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
m = GEKKO(remote=False)

m.time=np.linspace(0.000,0.046875,300)
#Variables
t = m.Param(m.time) #Time
h2 = 4.907/180*math.pi #arm 각도범위
beta2 = 40/360*2*math.pi #cam 할부각

rr1 = 292 #length of link1
rr2 = 398 #length of link2
rr3 = 130 #length of link3
rr0 = 429.71 #length of link0

rr11 = 260
rr22 = 639.5
rr33 = 260

theta20 = 112.4853/360*2*math.pi
theta25 = 2*math.pi/3*t 
theta200 = math.pi/2
theta233 = 0

rr00 = m.Var() #output 2
rr000 = m.Var() #Velocity of output
rr0000 = m.Var() #acceleration of output

# Input 1
theta21 = m.Intermediate(-math.pi+h2/2-h2*(0.43989*theta25/beta2-0.035014*m.sin(4*math.pi*theta25/beta2)))
A2 = m.Intermediate(2*rr0*rr3*m.cos(theta20)-2*rr1*rr3*m.cos(theta21))
B2 = m.Intermediate(2*rr0*rr3*m.sin(theta20)-2*rr1*rr3*m.sin(theta21))
C2 = m.Intermediate(rr0**2+rr1**2+rr3**2-rr2**2-2*rr0*rr1*(m.cos(theta20)*m.cos(theta21)+m.sin(theta20)*m.sin(theta21)))
K2 = m.Intermediate((-B2-(B2**2-C2**2+A2**2)**(1/2))/(C2-A2))
theta23 = m.Intermediate(m.atan(K2)*2)
theta211 = m.Intermediate(theta23 + math.pi)

AA2 = m.Intermediate(2*rr33*(m.cos(theta200)*m.cos(theta233)+m.sin(theta200)*m.sin(theta233))-2*rr11*(m.cos(theta200)*m.cos(theta211)+m.sin(theta200)*m.sin(theta211)))
BB2 = m.Intermediate(rr11**2+rr33**2-rr22**2-2*rr11*rr33*(m.cos(theta211)*m.cos(theta233)+m.sin(theta211)*m.sin(theta233)))

m.Equation((2*rr00+AA2)**2 == AA2**2-4*BB2)
m.Equation(rr00.dt()==rr000)
m.Equation(rr000.dt()==rr0000)

m.options.IMODE=4
m.options.SOLVER=3
m.solve(disp=True)
df = pd.DataFrame([m.time, rr00.value])
df.to_csv('test.csv',index=None)
plt.plot(m.time, rr00.value)
plt.show()
```

Here is the solver output:

```
iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
   0 0.0000000e+000 1.63e+006 0.00e+000   0.0 0.00e+000    -  0.00e+000 0.00e+000   0
   1 0.0000000e+000 3.10e+005 0.00e+000 -11.0 3.60e+011    -  1.00e+000 6.25e-002h  5
   2 0.0000000e+000 1.81e+004 0.00e+000 -11.0 2.74e+009    -  1.00e+000 1.00e+000h  1
   3 0.0000000e+000 4.97e+001 0.00e+000 -11.0 1.43e+008    -  1.00e+000 1.00e+000h  1
   4 0.0000000e+000 3.77e-004 0.00e+000 -11.0 3.95e+005    -  1.00e+000 1.00e+000h  1
   5 0.0000000e+000 6.98e-010 0.00e+000 -11.0 3.00e+000    -  1.00e+000 1.00e+000h  1

Number of Iterations....: 5

                                   (scaled)                 (unscaled)
Objective...............:  0.0000000000000000e+000   0.0000000000000000e+000
Dual infeasibility......:  0.0000000000000000e+000   0.0000000000000000e+000
Constraint violation....:  4.0017713930875105e-010   6.9849193096160889e-010
Complementarity.........:  0.0000000000000000e+000   0.0000000000000000e+000
Overall NLP error.......:  4.0017713930875105e-010   6.9849193096160889e-010


Number of objective function evaluations             = 10
Number of objective gradient evaluations             = 6
Number of equality constraint evaluations            = 11
Number of inequality constraint evaluations          = 0
Number of equality constraint Jacobian evaluations   = 6
Number of inequality constraint Jacobian evaluations = 0
Number of Lagrangian Hessian evaluations             = 5
Total CPU secs in IPOPT (w/o function evaluations)   =      0.045
Total CPU secs in NLP function evaluations           =      0.175

EXIT: Optimal Solution Found.

 The solution was found.

 The final value of the objective function is  0.

 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  IPOPT (v3.12)
 Solution time  :  0.24009999999999998 sec
 Objective      :  0.
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
```

As you modify the problem, also try the APOPT solver with `m.options.SOLVER=1` to see if that improves performance. I changed the `IMODE` to simulation (4) because there are zero degrees of freedom. You will need to change it back to `IMODE=6` if you introduce decision variables and an objective function.